# best practices for using Sencha Touch 2.0 build commands with Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha Touch 2.0 and I'm trying to integrate it into an existing Rails 3.0 project. I've:

1. Installed the latest sdk (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/)
2. Completed the tutorial Getting Started with Sencha Touch 2 (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started)
3. Read through [this tutorial](http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1/) and [pt2](http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-%E2%80%93-part-2/) on  on integrating Sencha Touch 1 with Rails.

.. but the material above (the best I found) never mentions the Sencha Touch 2: `sencha build` command and how to integrate with Rails 3.0.

`sencha build` for example creates a /diff directory, which is cool, but breaks my app, as one minor example.

Does anyone know some best practices/guidelines on how to integrate Sencha Touch 2 with rails 3.0 (not rails 3.1) especially using the `sencha build` command?

Thank you!